# isolate Lua scripts in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to integrate Lua into my program via LuaJIT.

Here's the requirement: scripts are obligated to define specific functions (such as `on_update()`, etc.), and these will be invoked from the C++ side. A single script can be loaded multiple times, but each instance should operate independently of the others.

I've considered several approaches to achieve this:

1. **Using separate `lua_State*` instances for each script.**

   - **Pros:** Easily isolates each script.
   - **Cons:** Seems to introduce unnecessary overhead.
2. **Isolating scripts with `lua_setfenv`:**

```cpp
lua_newtable(L);
int env = lua_gettop(L);
luaL_loadfile(L, "my_script.lua");
lua_pushvalue(L, env);
lua_setfenv(L, -2);
lua_call(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET);

int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

I believe this approach provides proper isolation for the scripts.

3. **Simply loading and referencing the script:**

```
luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

- **Cons:** The major downside is the potential for global variables to introduce elusive bugs, particularly when scripts are authored by multiple contributors.

I've been unable to find detailed information or best practices for this. Can anyone provide insights or recommend the best approach?

Comment: Using `setfenv` alone does not provide proper isolation. Even if you gave them completely different environments, the string metatable for example would still be shared. Are your isolation concerns security or interoperability concerns (are scripts trusted)?

Comment: @Luatic My primary concerns are security, reliability, and performance. These scripts are used for financial analysis, making it essential to maintain a secure environment. While I trust the intentions of the script developers, I'm wary of unintentional errors that might impact the system. Such errors can be challenging to debug, especially if they inadvertently affect other scripts. Therefore, I want to ensure that each script runs in a confined context, minimizing the risk of one script inadvertently impacting others, while still maintaining optimal execution speed